# Creating Holidays Predictor Dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I am working on an univeristy project and I have to build a dataframe which has just a datetime column to begin with.

What I have to do is add some predictors, such as my birthday, Christmas day, adding for each predictor a boolean column.

I've started extracting the month-day from a timestamp column but it's not working.

```
create_dataframe_predictors <- function(df)
{
  # Extracting Month and Datfrom Date
  df$MONTH_DAY <- format(as.Date(df$Date), "%m-%d")
  df$MY_BDAY <- NA
  ifelse(df$MONTH_DAY == "01-09", df$MY_BDAY = 1, df$MY_BDAY = 0)
  return (df)
} 
df <- create_dataframe_predictors(df)
```

So far nothing seems to work.

Here is what I'd like:

| DATE | MONTH_DAY | MY_BDAY | CHRISTMAS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 01-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 01:00:00 | 01-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-01-09 00:00:00 | 01-09 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-09 00:00:00 | 01-09 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-12-25 00:00:00 | 12-25 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-12-25 01:00:00 | 12-25 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a function for your problem. You can use `mutate` function from `dplyr` to create new columns with conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c('2022-01-01 00:00:00',
                                  '2022-01-02 00:00:00',
                                  '2022-12-25 00:00:00',
                                  '2022-12-25 01:00:00')))

df$Month_Day <- format(as.Date(df$Date), "%m-%d")

df %>%
  mutate(christmas = ifelse(Month_Day == "12-25", 1, 0),
         my_bday = ifelse(Month_Day == "01-02", 1, 0))
```